# Correctly align footers with flextable()

Tags: r, tidyverse, flextable

Is there a way that I can apply different alignments to a footer row in a flextable object? In the example below, I would like the first cell of the footer row to be left-aligned and the rest of the cells to be center-aligned.
Thank you.

```
library(tidyverse)
df<-data.frame(
  var1=rep(c('A', 'B'), 10),
  var2=rep(c('apples', 'oranges'), 10), 
  var3=rnorm(20),
  var4=rnorm(20), 
  var5=rnorm(20))
library(flextable)
flextable(df) %>% 
  add_footer_row(values=c('nobs', nrow(df), nrow(df), nrow(df)), colwidths=c(2,1,1,1)) %>% 
  align(., align="center", part="footer")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are after? Apply `align` twice but in order. `align(align = "center", part = "footer")` first to center the whole footer and then once more just to pick out the cell you want: `align(i = NULL, j = 1, align = "left", part = "footer")`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)
df <- data.frame(
  var1=rep(c('A', 'B'), 10),
  var2=rep(c('apples', 'oranges'), 10), 
  var3=rnorm(20),
  var4=rnorm(20), 
  var5=rnorm(20))
flextable(df) %>% 
  add_footer_row(values = c('nobs', nrow(df), nrow(df), nrow(df)), colwidths=c(2, 1, 1, 1)) %>% 
  align(align = "center", part = "footer") %>% 
  align(i = NULL, j = 1, align = "left", part = "footer")
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks, I missed that the footer could have multiple rows or columns and the i and j selectors could be used to be applied to those table parts. Logical, but I missed it.